# Custom tpl.php for custom content types rendered through another tpl.php

Tags: theming, nodes

I have a custom module which displays multiple content types in tabs. My module uses a custom `tpl.php` which renders the tabs and the contents(of multiple types).

The challenge is to have custom *tpl.php* for each content types I render. The theme file *node--TYPE.tpl.php* works when I directly hit a node of a *TYPE*. But it is not used when I rendered the node content using the below code,

```
    $node = node_load($aTab['nid']);
    $view = node_view($node, 'full');
    $rendered = drupal_render($view);
    print_r($rendered);
```

What is the suggestion to have my module to render each content types using their custom theme file.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be printing it with [print_r()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php), just try [print](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print.php).

```
$node = node_load($aTab['nid']);
$view = node_view($node, 'full');
print drupal_render($view);
```